# Is this possible: Django TestCase + async + db calls?

Tags: django, database, asynchronous, testcase

I have an error when use db calls in async methods of Django TestCase: "psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed"

I know that I can use TransactionTestCase, but it's slow.
Is there solution for this using Django TestCase?

**example.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

async def func():
    return await database_sync_to_async(get_user_model().objects.filter(pk=1).exists)()
```

**test_example.py**

```py
import django.test
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

from .example import func

class TestFunc(django.test.TestCase):
    async def test_func(self):
        res = await func()
        await sync_to_async(self.assertFalse)(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only needed to replace `database_sync_to_async` with `sync_to_async` :)